# Excel vba plink issue

Tags: linux, vba, excel, plink

I'm trying to get Excel VBA to run a list of commands on a Linux server.

I used the following:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

cmd = plink & " -ssh -P 22 " & ip & " -l " & username & " -i " & ppk & " -m " & commands_file & " -t "

Set oEx = objShell.Exec(cmd)
```

where `commands_file` contains the following:

```
sudo su - root

/opt/ibm/ccm/collectLogs.sh
```

When I run it the VB script appears a command line for a while and after it disappears without appearing to run the given instructions on commands_file.

Where is the error?

Please let me know.

I'd like to have a command window opened and see it run the collectLogs without it closing after finished.

Comment: See [Plink is not switching user using su command](https://superuser.com/q/1234230/213663).

Comment: Thank you.I saw it but didn't help. It seems I'm obliged to use the ppk to become root